# Sencha Command failing native android packaging on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, extjs, cordova

I am on a dual-boot windows 8/Ubuntu machine. The same piece of code works fine on Windows 8, but fails on ubuntu, when I fire **sencha app build native** command.

I am trying to package android app, and using **Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84**.

Below is the error log tail:

```
[INF] init:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-phonegap-init:
[INF] 
[INF] -phonegap-init:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-phonegap-init:
[INF] 
[INF] phonegap-init:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-phonegap:
[INF] 
[INF] phonegap-copy-build:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-phonegap-copy-build:
[INF] 
[INF] -phonegap-copy-build:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-phonegap-copy-build:
[INF] 
[INF] -phonegap-build:
[INF] 
[INF] -phonegap-local-build:
[INF] [shellscript] [phonegap] compiling Android...
[INF] [shellscript] [ReferenceError: a is not defined]
[INF] [shellscript] execvp(): Permission denied
[INF] [shellscript] '{' [Error: /home/compUser/projWorkspace/proj/SomeApp/phonegap/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code EACCES] code: '''EACCES''' '}'
[INF] [shellscript]    [error] /home/compUser/projWorkspace/proj/SomeApp/phonegap/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code EACCES
[INF] 
[INF] -phonegap-run:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-phonegap:
[INF] 
[INF] -native-package:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-native-package:
[INF] 
[INF] -build:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-build:
[INF] 
[INF] build:
[INF] 
[INF] app-build:
```

When I cd to the directory: */home/compUser/projWorkspace/proj/SomeApp/phonegap/platforms/android/cordova/build*, and fire "phonegap local build android", I get the same error, which is,

```
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[ReferenceError: a is not defined]
execvp(): Permission denied
{ [Error: /home/devesh/rxWorkspace/rx/RxApp/phonegap/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code EACCES] code: 'EACCES' }
   [error] /home/devesh/rxWorkspace/rx/RxApp/phonegap/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code EACCES
```

I am wondering if something is wrong with the phonegap configuration on ubuntu.

PS: I have thoroughly verified the file-system permissions, and its not an issue.

Comment: got the same problem!

Comment: So, I actually use the phonegap remote build system, instead of the local build. Its pretty harmless so far, all that you need to be connected to the internet. However, I do not know how to link it to a CI, surely there would be a way.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I resolve it typing

```
$ android
```

and installing all subpackages of API version that I need.